# Retired Content Model View Presenter on MSDN

Tags: winforms, mvp

I am learning to develop windows forms application with Entity Framework using Model View Presenter pattern, since it is the suggested design pattern for windows forms development on stackoverflow. On the other hand, there is a 'retired content' note on every article about MVP, on MSDN.
This is quite confusing, as I don't whether I should continue learning about MVP and try to implement it in windows forms development or there is another better design pattern that I should follow.
Any suggestion?

links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647543.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649820.aspx

Comment: Provide some links so we can check them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For WinForms you should stick with [MVP (Supervising Controller)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html).

The reason you are seeing retired content is because Microsoft is heavily invested in the new Windows 8, [Metro Style applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464920.aspx). [WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) built using C++, C# and [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx),  or [HTML5 + JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx) are going to be what you will build applications in going forward, so it makes sense to learn *at least* one of those.

WinForms isn't officially deprecated, but don't expect it to get a lot of love from MS. I would spend some time learning [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx), and the [MVVM pattern](http://wpftutorial.net/MVVM.html). That being said, the concepts for all [UI design patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) (MVC, MVP, MVVM) are all very similar, so learning one will help you understand the others.

Comment: Thank a lot for this nice answer. I guess its time to switch to WPF :)